# Finding $\mathrm{cov}(Y,Z)$ where $Y=X_1+2X_2$, $Z=X_1-2X_2$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent

Tags: probability

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent random variables with mean $ \mu\in \mathbb{R}$ and variance $\sigma^2 > 0$. 
Then, let $Y = X_1 + 2X_2$ and Z = $X_1 - 2X_2$. I want to say something about $\operatorname{cov}(Y,Z)$. I know that$$\operatorname{cov}(Y,Z) = E[YZ]-E[Y]E[Z]= E[X_1^2 - 4X_2^2] - (\mu + 2\mu)(\mu - 2\mu).$$
And now I am stuck because I do now know how to find $E[X_1^2]$.

Any help? I think I should work with the variance maybe?

Comment: Yes.  Work with the variance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sigma^2 = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Another route (making use of bilinearity and symmetry of covariance).

$$\begin{array}{cl}
&\mathsf{Cov}(X_1+2X_2,X_1-2X_2) \\
=& \mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_1)-2\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)+2\mathsf{Cov}(X_2,X_1)-4\mathsf{Cov}(X_2,X_2) \\
=& \mathsf{Var}X_1-4\mathsf{Var}X_2
\end{array}$$

Note that this is also true if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dependent (because of the symmetry telling us that $\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=\mathsf{Cov}(X_2,X_1)$).